# How to keep and add items in a List of objects during button click events

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I want to add new items to my generic list when user clicks on a button, but each the the list contains only the last introduced item, it seems that during each button click list get reinitialized :(.

This is a part of code:

```
 List<ProdusBon> listaProduseBon = new List<ProdusBon>();

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listaProduseBon.Add(new ProdusBon(-1, Int32.Parse(TextBox2.Text), -1, Int32.Parse (ListBox1.SelectedValue)));
}
```

I also tried using this code:

```
 List<ProdusBon> listaProduseBon = null;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
       listaProduseBon = new List<ProdusBon>();
    }
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listaProduseBon.Add(new ProdusBon(-1, Int32.Parse(TextBox2.Text), -1, Int32.Parse (ListBox1.SelectedValue)));
}
```

but in this case a null reference exception was raised.

I must keep all the items in the list and not only the last one, and when click event was raised a new item to be added to the list.

All the controls in Default.aspx got the default values only the ListBox has "Enable AutoPostBack" set to true but i believe that this is not causing this behavior.

I do not how to keep the items in the list in these conditions, please give me a hand if you know how to do this.

Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Member variables are lost between page loads. You could store the variable in Session if you want it to remain the same value between loads.

```
List<ProdusBon> listaProduseBon
{
   get { return (List<ProdusBon>) Session["ProdusBon"]; }
   set { Session["ProdusBon"] = value; }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (listaProduseBon == null) listaProduseBon = new List<ProdusBon>();
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listaProduseBon.Add(new ProdusBon(-1, Int32.Parse(TextBox2.Text), -1, Int32.Parse (ListBox1.SelectedValue)));
}
```

Comment: Hi , thank you for posting i am using this version but i am getting this exception:

Comment: [A]System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ProdusBon] cannot be cast to [B]System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ProdusBon]. Type A originates from 'mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' in the context 'LoadNeither' at location 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Type B originates from 'mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' in the context 'LoadNeither' at location 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'.

Comment: @Mircea That's not a problem with the code. There's something else screwed up in your solution. Try Build > Clean Solution then Build > Build Solution.

Comment: @Mircea In fact, if it continues to be a problem, start a new question. Because that issue is definitely not because of the answer I have given - it's a build error due to an odd conflict between the same type and the same DLLs. Strange.

Comment: Hi Roy, yes i checked the code also in debug and usually it is working fine,it seems that only if i start and restart the solution in the same session this is happening , if i restart also the browser this is not happening any more until i stop and restart the solution ( web site ) in the same open session.

Comment: Thank you a lot for help ! This is a valid solution ;) for me.

Answer (score 0):

On your button click event first bind the list button and then add the new item from the textbox.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //code to bind your list goes here
    listaProduseBon.Add(new ProdusBon(-1, Int32.Parse(TextBox2.Text), -1, Int32.Parse (ListBox1.SelectedValue)));
}
```

Comment: Hi, i want to use this collection in another events, so this collection is not seen as a "local" variable only for this event